# Steam Web API Condensing

Tags: php, steam-web-api

I searched around for the answer to this but couldn't find anything and was looking for help from you wonderful people.  I have been toying around with steam web API for my site.  I have found this code and am using it.  Also, I have barely any experience in steam api, most of my experience is in C.  Anyway, here is the code:

```
[insert_php]
$api = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=MyApiKey&steamid=MySteamId&format=json";
$json = (file_get_contents($api));
$schema = json_decode($json);   
print var_dump($schema); 
[/insert_php]
```

I am using a plugin and inserting this php into my WordPress page.  This code goes into my steam backpack and gives me all the items I have in a complicated list.  What I need help with is condensing it so that it can be easily read.  A defining feature of the inventory items is the defindexes.  What I want to do is have it so if it finds a certain amount of one item with the same defindex, it will return that amount like this into my page: Scrap Metal = # of defindexes of Scrap Metal found.  I hope that this is clear enough and that there is an answer.  Thank you.

Part of my code that is returned now:

```
{
                "id": 1828947688,
                "original_id": 1176490973,
                "defindex": 5009,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483650,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947700,
                "original_id": 1176491289,
                "defindex": 5009,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483651,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947742,
                "original_id": 1178541917,
                "defindex": 5009,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483652,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947755,
                "original_id": 1178542060,
                "defindex": 5009,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483757,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947766,
                "original_id": 1179066746,
                "defindex": 5005,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483653,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947780,
                "original_id": 1181421843,
                "defindex": 5009,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483756,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947788,
                "original_id": 1181426745,
                "defindex": 5006,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483654,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947793,
                "original_id": 1187413384,
                "defindex": 5007,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483755,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947796,
                "original_id": 1187413535,
                "defindex": 5007,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483655,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947801,
                "original_id": 1187416362,
                "defindex": 5007,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483754,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947810,
                "original_id": 1190342559,
                "defindex": 5013,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483656,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947826,
                "original_id": 1190342965,
                "defindex": 5013,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483753,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 1828947835,
                "original_id": 1243518373,
                "defindex": 5011,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 6,
                "inventory": 2147483657,
                "quantity": 1,
                "origin": 4
            }
ETC.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through each item in your result `$schema` and search for the defindexes you are looking for.

For example, if you want to count all of your metal, you'll be looking for `5000`, `5001`, and `5002`.

```
$metal_array = array(5000, 5001, 5002);
foreach ($schema as $item)
{
    if (in_array($metal_array, $item->defindex)
    {
        // Do something for the $item. Presumably, you'll add these up 
        // So that you can get a total metal count (remember that refined is worth 9 scrap  
        // and reclaimed is worth 3)
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

To answer some of the questions in your comment:

`$item->defindex` is referring to the `defindex` of the current `$item` object in your schema. You are performing [object iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) in this [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. Each `item` is being iterated over in the `foreach` loop. So, on the first pass through the loop, `$item` will look like this:

```
        {
            "id": 1828947688,
            "original_id": 1176490973,
            "defindex": 5009,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 6,
            "inventory": 2147483650,
            "quantity": 1,
            "origin": 4
        }
```

You can access any of these values by doing `$item->ATTRIBUTENAME` (ie. `$item->quality` or `$item->origin`). On this pass through the loop, it will check if `$item->defindex`, which equals `5009` is in the `$metal_array`, which contains `5000`, `5001, and`5002`. It does not, so the if block does not execute.

As for what you'd do in that loop, I'd probably modify the code slightly to do something like this:

```
$metal_array = array(5000, 5001, 5002);
$total_metal = 0;
foreach ($schema as $item)
{
    if (in_array($metal_array, $item->defindex)
    {
        switch ($item->defindex)
        {
            case 5000:
               $total_metal++;     // or $total_metal += 1;
               break;
            case 5001:
               $total_metal += 3;
               break;
            case 5002:
               $total_metal += 9;
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of this block, you will have a value in `$total_metal` that equals the scrap value of all of your metal.

This block uses the [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement to determine how much a particular item is worth. The [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) statement within each `case` prevents the logic from "falling through" to the next option.

For example, if the `break` was not added to the end of the `case 5000` block of code and an `$item->defindex` equaled `5000`, it would add `1` and then `3`. This is not the answer you want. It is, however, a valid option to consider in certain circumstances.

```
        switch ($item->defindex)
        {
            case 5000:
               $total_metal++;     // or $total_metal += 1;
            case 5001:
               $total_metal += 3;
               break;
         }
```

Finally, if you are new to PHP, I recommend taking a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: Thanks.   I hate doing this because I would rather look it up myself but I tried looking it up and I am still confused.  What would I put in the brackets?  From what I see the if statement looks in the array for 5000, 5001, and 5002.  I have no clue what the $item->defindex means because I have no clue how to code in this format and do not know where to learn.  Again, I hate doing this and I understand if you do not answer due to this being to localized or you don't like spoon feeding me the answers but it would be appreciated if you could help.